# Global Address Book with IMAP

Tags: email

I have just bought a domain and hosting and I am about to setup email (IMAP) addressed for my users (100+).

As most of them do not know each other’s email. I like to setup a Global Address Book where they can search each other’s email address by name etc.

Does anyone know any way or any 3rd party Add-in/ software that can allow me to setup a Global Address Book on IMAP? (I do not mind paying)

I know it is possible on Exchange.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! The question that you're asking is about a server that happens to be on the internet, but isn't really about being a webmaster.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally LDAP services are used for directory services. Whoever if hosting your IMAP might offer a directory service as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

If you planning use webmail, http://roundcube.net/ include global addressbook that is very easy to configure.